# Tortoise SVN pre-commit script allow commit that contains defined string

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

Creating a pre commit script that will only allow commits that contain a specific string somewhere in the file Test.cfg

Currently I have it working in that it will look through every file committed and blocks commits that contain a specified string

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook


$SVNLOOK diff -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
   grep -i "Sting to search here" > /dev/null && { echo "String exists so block commit" 1>&2; exit 1; }
```

What I am after is for the above code to pretty do the complete opposite so that if the string exists allow the commit and if not then prevent the commit. It would also be nice if I could specify which file should be searched as currently it searches every file and some of the commits can contain 1000's of files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beg your pardon, but `svnlook diff` in your case is ugly stupid way. Re-read svnlook subcommands t[opic in SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.html), pay attention to `svnlook tree`/`svnlook changed` + `svnlook cat`

Full business-logic of your test can|have to be something like (I'm too lazy to write full bashism here, it will be your duty)

**IF** `$FILENAME` exist in transaction ( I'll prefer `svnlook tree --full-paths ...` just because `svnlook changed ...` will require additional `| gawk {print $2}` for clean filename) **AND** `$FILENAME` contains `$STRING` (`svnlook cat "$FILENAME" | grep "STRING" ...`) **DO SOMETHING**

Don't forget also process possible edge cases:

- $FILENAME doesn't exist in transaction, but presented in WC with correct $STRING, but file *not modified* according to svn status
- The same as above, but *modified*
- pp 1-2, but with disallow $STRING

Due to above notes, I'll recommend to explore|check possibility of replacing file+string by testing *custom revision's property* in hook (shorter, easier, more manageable)